# My IMAC 27" points to python2.7 how to update

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I have installed the latest version of python3 and it shows in my application folder, but when I use the command line and ask for the version it is the factory version of 2.7. How do I change this for someone who is really basic with command line and other. I have read other posts and what to put in the command line exactly but get syntax errors. I heard about brew. Why is it so hard to do something so simple. Can I just change the command line to point to the new python3 automatically without using another 3rd party thing. Hope you can help and sorry for frustration.

Comment: is it registered as `python3`?

Comment: I downloaded the latest python yesterday and installed it. Now, when I pull up the commmand line and type python --version it comes up 2.7